# Field name not working in QGIS Modeler expression?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression, qgis-modeler

Why does the Field Calculator expression using field name work in the Attribute table but not in the QGIS Modeler?

Answer (score 7):

Because, an expression in the Field Calculator is related to the current attribute table, as in the first image.

[image]

But models are created for general purposes (for any layer) and it is not layer-specific. Therefore, it's a reasonable approach that the expression using field name works in the attribute table, but doesn't work in the model. So, if you need to use a field in a model, you need to add "Vector Field" input for the field.

[image]